# Spynner под Windows

Tags: python, windows

Кто-то писал на Python с использование модуля Spynner? Есть скрипт, писаный под линуксом, под ним же затестированный. И нужно запустить его под Windows. Какие подводные камни, как его запустить?

Answer (score 1):

Использовал spynner и под виндоус и под линуксом, работает одинаково. Подводные камни в самом spynner, камней в запуске его нет.